# Still can't get sort and search an array to work

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting, search

I am becoming bitter and resentful in the process. My tutor is not responding to my calls for over a week. This is my last attempt. I got all my code working besides two things.
1. I can search in my array but I do only get the first right answer, I want all hits back to the console.
2. I get exception error on my bubble sort and I have no clue what I am doing. I can bubble sort an array that is one-dimensional filled with integers all fine.

My problem is that I can not handle the transition of an array going from one dimension to multiple dimensions. I do not understand the implications of choosing 'for (int i = 0; i < bottleCount(); i++)' over 'foreach(var bottle in bottles)'. It seems to me if I want to add money up I am better of with the first. However when I want some answers out of the array foreach is not the tool to use. Some times bottles.xyz is working while other times bottleS.xyz is working.

Please understand that I am a noob and mostly self tutored by reading books. I am taking a web class to learn more but my teacher isn't helpful and I am frustrated to tears while I try to understand. I believe I am pretty close but I need a dumbed down help that does not require me to understand the finer points. The teacher indicates that I should use ToString to somehow get my search and bubblesort my sodacrate. I am more inclined to actually learn how to get my kit together with my array properly. Failing that I can accept the ToString solution which totally eludes me.

I put all my working code at the bottom and I removed my menu from Run() to make testing more efficient. If anyone could help me I would be grateful else I will hand in my work as is with my menu reinstated. I want to understand and learn though.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Sodacrate
{
//Soda - contains the properties for the bottles that go in to the crate
class Soda : IComparable<Soda>
{
string drinkName;
string drinkType;
int drinkPrice;
int productCode;

//Construct for the beverage
public Soda(string _drinkName, string _drinkType, int _drinkPrice, int _productCode)
{
drinkName = _drinkName;
drinkType = _drinkType;
drinkPrice = _drinkPrice;
productCode = _productCode;
}

//Property for the drink name e.g. Coca Cola, Ramlösa or Pripps lättöl
public string Drink_name
{
get { return drinkName; }
set { drinkName = value; }
}

//Property for the drink type e.g. Soda, fizzy water or beer
public string Drink_type
{
get { return drinkType; }
set { drinkType = value; }
}

//Property for the drink price in SEK
public int Drink_price
{
get { return drinkPrice; }
set { drinkPrice = value; }
}

//Property for the product code e.g. 1, 2 or ...
public int Product_code
{
get { return productCode; }
set { productCode = value; }
}

//Override for ToString to get text instead of info about the object
public override string ToString()
{
return string.Format("{0} is a {1} costs {2} productcode {3} ", drinkName, drinkType, drinkPrice, productCode);
//return string.Format("{0,0} Type {1,-16} Price {2,-10} Code {3, -5} ", drinkName, drinkType, drinkPrice, productCode);
}

//Compare to solve my issues with sorting
public int CompareTo(Soda other)
{
if (ReferenceEquals(other, null))
return 1;

return drinkName.CompareTo(other.drinkName);
}

}

static class Screen
{
// Screen - Generic methods for handling in- and output ======================================= >

// Methods for screen handling in this object are:
//
//  cls()       Clear screen
//  cup(row, col)       Positions the curser to a position on the console
//  inKey()             Reads one pressed key (Returned value is : ConsoleKeyInfo)
//  inStr()         Handles String
//  inInt()     Handles Int
//  inFloat()       Handles Float(Singel)
//  meny()              Menu system , first invariable is Rubrik and 2 to 6 meny choises
//  addSodaMenu()       The options for adding bottles

// Clear Screen  ------------------------------------------
static public void cls()
{
Console.Clear();
}

// Set Curser Position  ----------------------------------
static public void cup(int column, int rad)
{
Console.SetCursorPosition(column, rad);
}

// Key Input --------------------------------------------
static public ConsoleKeyInfo inKey()
{
ConsoleKeyInfo in_key; in_key = Console.ReadKey(); return in_key;
}

// String Input -----------------------------------------
static public string inStr()
{
string in_string; in_string = Console.ReadLine(); return in_string;
}

// Int Input -------------------------------------------
static public int inInt()
{
int int_in; try { int_in = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); }
catch (FormatException) { Console.WriteLine("Input Error \b"); int_in = 0; }
catch (OverflowException) { Console.WriteLine("Input Owerflow\b"); int_in = 0; }
return int_in;
}

// Float Input -------------------------------------------
static public float inFloat()
{
float float_in; try { float_in = Convert.ToSingle(Console.ReadLine()); }
catch (FormatException) { Console.WriteLine("Input Error \b"); float_in = 0; }
catch (OverflowException) { Console.WriteLine("Input Owerflow\b"); float_in = 0; }
return float_in;
}

// Menu ------------------------------------------------
static public int meny(string rubrik, string m_val1, string m_val2)
{  // Meny med 2 val ---------------------
int menSvar; menyRubrik(rubrik); menyRad(m_val1); menyRad(m_val2); menSvar = menyInm();
return menSvar;
}

static public int meny(string rubrik, string m_val1, string m_val2, string m_val3)
{  // Meny med 3 val ---------------------
int menSvar; menyRubrik(rubrik); menyRad(m_val1); menyRad(m_val2); menyRad(m_val3); menSvar = menyInm();
return menSvar;
}

static public int meny(string rubrik, string m_val1, string m_val2, string m_val3, string m_val4)
{  // Meny med 4 val ---------------------
int menSvar; menyRubrik(rubrik); menyRad(m_val1); menyRad(m_val2); menyRad(m_val3); menyRad(m_val4); menSvar = menyInm();
return menSvar;
}

static public int meny(string rubrik, string m_val1, string m_val2, string m_val3, string m_val4, string m_val5)
{  // Meny med 5 val ---------------------
int menSvar; menyRubrik(rubrik); menyRad(m_val1); menyRad(m_val2); menyRad(m_val3); menyRad(m_val4); menyRad(m_val5); menSvar = menyInm();
return menSvar;
}

static public int meny(string rubrik, string m_val1, string m_val2, string m_val3, string m_val4, string m_val5, string m_val6)
{  // Meny med 6 val ---------------------
int menSvar; menyRubrik(rubrik); menyRad(m_val1); menyRad(m_val2); menyRad(m_val3); menyRad(m_val4); menyRad(m_val5); ; menyRad(m_val6); menSvar = menyInm();
return menSvar;
}

static void menyRubrik(string rubrik)
{   // Meny rubrik --------
cls(); Console.WriteLine("\n\t {0}\n----------------------------------------------------\n", rubrik);
}

static void menyRad(string menyVal)
{   // Meny rad    --------
Console.WriteLine("\t {0}", menyVal);
}

static int menyInm()
{ // Meny inmating ------
int mVal; Console.Write("\n\t Menyval : "); mVal = inInt(); return mVal;
}

// Menu for adding bottles --------------------------------
static public void addSodaMenu()
{
cls();
Console.WriteLine("\tChoose a beverage please.");
Console.WriteLine("\t1. Coca Cola");
Console.WriteLine("\t2. Champis");
Console.WriteLine("\t3. Grappo");
Console.WriteLine("\t4. Pripps Blå lättöl");
Console.WriteLine("\t5. Spendrups lättöl");
Console.WriteLine("\t6. Ramlösa citron");
Console.WriteLine("\t7. Vichy Nouveu");
Console.WriteLine("\t9. Exit to main menu");
Console.WriteLine("\t--------------------\n");
}

// Screen - Slut  <========================================
} // screen <----

class Sodacrate
{
// Sodacrate - Methods for handling arrays and lists of Soda-objects ======================================= >

// Methods for Soda handling in this object are:
//
//  cls()       Clear screen
//
//

private Soda[] bottles;             //Create they array where we store the up to 25 bottles
private int numberOfBottles = 0;          //Keep track of the number of bottles in the crate

//Not working
public int find_Soda(string drinkname)
{
//Notes from teatcher   **=================start==================**
//You should be able to search for name
//You can use string-methods ToLower() or ToUpper() 
//Notes from teatcher   **=================end====================**

for (int i = 0; i < bottles.Length; i++)
{
if (bottles[i].Drink_name == drinkname) //My feeble attempts
return i;
}
return -1;
}

//Exception error
public void sort_Sodas()
{
int max = bottles.Length;
//Outer loop for complete [bottles]
for (int i = 1; i < max; i++)
{
//Inner loop for row by row
int nrLeft = max - i;
for (int j = 0; j < (max - i); j++)
{
if (bottles[j].Product_code > bottles[j + 1].Product_code)
{
int temp = bottles[j].Product_code;
bottles[j] = bottles[j + 1];
bottles[j + 1].Product_code = temp;
}
}
}
}

//Exception error
public void sort_Sodas_name()
{
int max = bottles.Length;
//Outer loop for complete [bottles]
for (int i = 1; i < max; i++)
{
//Inner loop for row by row
int nrLeft = max - i;
for (int j = 0; j < (max - i); j++)
{
//Error CS0122  'Soda.drinkName' is inaccessible due to its protection level
if (bottles[j].drinkName > bottles[j + 1].drinkName)
{
//int temp = bottles[j].drinkName;
//bottles[j] = bottles[j + 1];
//bottles[j + 1].drinkName = temp;*/
}
}
}
}

//Search for Product code ony returns the first hit
public int LinearSearch(int key)
{

for (int i = 0; i < bottles.Length; i++)
{
if (bottles[i].Product_code == key)
return i;
}
return -1;
}

//Contains the menu to choose from the crates methods
public void Run()
{
//Quick and dirty add of data. I got this working fine
bottles[0] = new Soda("Coca Cola", "Soda", 5, 1);
bottles[1] = new Soda("Champis", "Soda", 6, 1);
bottles[2] = new Soda("Grappo", "Soda", 4, 1);
bottles[3] = new Soda("Pripps Blå", "beer", 6, 2);
bottles[4] = new Soda("Spendrups", "beer", 6, 2);
bottles[5] = new Soda("Ramlösa", "water", 4, 3);
bottles[6] = new Soda("Loka", "water", 4, 3);
bottles[7] = new Soda("Coca Cola", "Soda", 5, 1);

print_crate();  //Happy with this one I need to shape up the ToString override
Console.WriteLine("\n\tYou have {0} bottles in your crate:\n\n", bottleCount());

Console.WriteLine("\nTotal value of the crate is {0}", calc_total());//Happy as a clam

/*int price = 0; //Causes exception error I lack understanding
foreach(var bottle in bottles)
{
price = price + bottle.Drink_price;
}
*/
//Console.WriteLine("\tThe total value of the crate is {0} SEK.", price);

Screen.inKey();
Screen.cls();

int test = 0;
test = bottles[3].Product_code;//So bottles[i].xyz  do some things and bottles.xyz others
Console.WriteLine("Product code {0} is in slot {1}", test, 3);
Screen.inKey();

//This only returns the first product with the asked productcode. How to get all? Also what if I searched for name like Coca Cola instead?
Console.WriteLine("Type 1, 2 or 3");
int prodcode = Screen.inInt();
Console.WriteLine(LinearSearch(prodcode));
Console.WriteLine("Product code {0} is in slot {1}", prodcode, (LinearSearch(prodcode)));
Console.WriteLine(bottles[(LinearSearch(prodcode))]);

Screen.inKey();
//sort_Sodas();         //Causes Exception error I want it to sort on either product code or product name
//print_crate();        //Check if the sort has put two Coca Cola on top.
}

//Print the content of the crate to the console
public void print_crate()
{
foreach (var beverage in bottles)
{
if (beverage != null)
Console.WriteLine(beverage);
}
Console.WriteLine("\n\tYou have {0} bottles in your crate:", bottleCount());
}

//Construct, sets the Sodacrate to hold 25 bottles
public Sodacrate()
{
bottles = new Soda[25];
}

// Count the ammounts of bottles in crate
public int bottleCount()
{
int cnt = numberOfBottles;
// Loop though array to get not empty element
foreach (var beverages in bottles)
{
if (beverages != null)
{
cnt++;
}
}
return cnt;
}

//Calculates the total value of the bottles in the crate
public int calc_total()
{
int temp = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < bottleCount(); i++)
{
temp = temp + (bottles[i].Drink_price);
}
return temp;
}
//Adds bottles in the crate.
public void add_Soda()
{
//I start of with adding 7 bottles to avoid having to add so many bottles testing functions. Remove block before release 
bottles[0] = new Soda("Coca Cola", "Soda", 5, 1);
bottles[1] = new Soda("Champis", "Soda", 6, 1);
bottles[2] = new Soda("Grappo", "Soda", 4, 1);
bottles[3] = new Soda("Pripps Blå", "lättöl", 6, 2);
bottles[4] = new Soda("Spendrups", "lättöl", 6, 2);
bottles[5] = new Soda("Ramlösa citron", "mineralvatten", 4, 3);
bottles[6] = new Soda("Vichy Nouveu", "mineralvatten", 4, 3);
//<====================================== End block

int beverageIn = 0;//Creates the menu choice-variable
while (beverageIn != 9)//Exit this menu by typing 9 - This value should be different if we add more bottle types to add.
{
Screen.addSodaMenu();//Calls the menu in the Screen-class
Console.WriteLine("You have {0} bottles in the crate.\n\nChoose :", bottleCount());
Screen.cup(8, 13);
int i = bottleCount();//Keeps track of how many bottles we have in the crate. If the crate is full we get expelled out of this method
if (i == 25)
{ beverageIn = 9; }
else beverageIn = Screen.inInt();//end

switch (beverageIn) //Loop for adding bottles to the crate exit by pressing 9
{
case 1:
i = bottleCount();
bottles[i] = new Soda("Coca Cola", "Soda", 5, 1);
i++;
break;

case 2:
i = bottleCount();
bottles[i] = new Soda("Champis", "Soda", 6, 1);
i++;
break;

case 3:
i = bottleCount();
bottles[i] = new Soda("Grappo", "Soda", 4, 1);
i++;
break;

case 4:
i = bottleCount();
bottles[i] = new Soda("Pripps Blå lättöl", "lättöl", 6, 2);
i++;
break;

case 5:
i = bottleCount();
bottles[i] = new Soda("Spendrups lättöl", "lättöl", 6, 2);
i++;
break;

case 6:
i = bottleCount();
bottles[i] = new Soda("Ramlösa citron", "mineralvatten", 4, 3);
i++;
break;

case 7:
i = bottleCount();
bottles[i] = new Soda("Vichy Nouveu", "mineralvatten", 4, 3);
i++;
break;

case 9:
i = bottleCount();
if (i == 25)
{
Console.WriteLine("\tThe crate is full\n\tGoing back to main menu. Press a key: ");
}
Console.WriteLine("Going back to main menu. Press a key: ");
break;

default://Default will never kick in as I have error handling in Screen.inInt()
Console.WriteLine("Error, pick a number between 1 and 7 or 9 to end.");
break;
}
}
}
// Sodacrate - End  <========================================

class Program
{
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
//Creates an object of class Sodacrate named Sodacrate
var Sodacrate = new Sodacrate();
Sodacrate.Run();
Console.Write("Press any key to continue . . . ");
Console.ReadKey(true);
}
}
}
}
```

Comment: First of all, could, please, *format out* your code? When code is *hard to read* it's difficult to debug as well.

Comment: OK. the first hit problem - yes it would do, you have told it start at 0, and work through each one, once you find one that has a product_code that matches key, stop and give back that number.  Look up the word yield or linq ..   Second, your sort - so would array.sort .. linq will handle that if you let it - Also, you have your comparable, but it only returns 1 if equal. you need -1 if more than, and 0 if equal and 1 if less than (yeah kinda the wrong way round in my head too) .. lastly exceptions.. you'd need to tell us what the exception is..

Comment: Dmitry I tried to format the code with CTRL-K. I am sad that it is not to your liking.

Comment: What IDE do you use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wow you've got allot of questions. I will try to answer as many as I can figure out. First of all your error with the for loop. You have the following code:

```
bottles = new Soda[25];
```

What this does is create an array which can contain 25 Soda items. The problem with your for loop is that you only only set the first 8 items and each item after that is null, which is why you are getting your error. Try something like this:

```
foreach (var bottle in bottles)
{
    if (bottle == null)
    {
        continue;
    }
    price = price + bottle.Drink_price;
}
```

What this does is essentially skip all bottle values which are null by using the `continue` statement. You could also use `break` but the first time it finds a null value it will stop processing the loop.

Again because of nulls your `sort_Sodas()` function should be something like this. Previously you were just changing the price and not switching the bottles, so I made that modification for you.

```
public void sort_Sodas()
{
    int max = bottles.Length;
    //Outer loop for complete [bottles]
    for (int i = 1; i < max; i++)
    {
        //Inner loop for row by row
        int nrLeft = max - i;
        for (int j = 0; j < (max - i); j++)
        {
            var bottle1 = bottles[j];
            var bottle2 = bottles[j + 1];

            if((bottle1 == null) || (bottle2 == null))
            {
                continue;
            }

            if (bottle1.Product_code > bottle2.Product_code)
            {
                var temp = bottles[j];
                bottles[j] = bottles[j + 1];
                bottles[j + 1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now for your I changed your `CompareTo` method in soda to this:

```
public int CompareTo(Soda other)
{
    if (other == null)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    return drinkName.CompareTo(other.drinkName);
}
```

and the actual `sort_Sodas_name()` function to this:

```
public void sort_Sodas_name()
{
    int max = bottles.Length;
    //Outer loop for complete [bottles]
    for (int i = 1; i < max; i++)
    {
        //Inner loop for row by row
        int nrLeft = max - i;
        for (int j = 0; j < (max - i); j++)
        {
            var bottle1 = bottles[j];
            var bottle2 = bottles[j + 1];

            if ((bottle1 == null) || (bottle2 == null))
            {
                continue;
            }
            //Error CS0122  'Soda.drinkName' is inaccessible due to its protection level
            if (bottle1.Drink_name.CompareTo(bottle2.Drink_name) == 1)
            {
                var temp = bottles[j];
                bottles[j] = bottles[j + 1];
                bottles[j + 1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The reason you were getting an inaccessible error on `Soda.drinkName` was because the `drinkName` variable is private, so I changed it to use `Soda.Drink_name` as that was your public getter and setter, which you already had.

For completeness here is the whole code, *please note that my `Program` class is at the top, instead of the bottom like you had:*

```
using System;

namespace Sodacrate
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Creates an object of class Sodacrate named Sodacrate
            var Sodacrate = new Sodacrate();
            Sodacrate.Run();
            Console.Write("Press any key to continue . . . ");
            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }
    }

    //Soda - contains the properties for the bottles that go in to the crate
    class Soda : IComparable<Soda>
    {
        string drinkName;
        string drinkType;
        int drinkPrice;
        int productCode;

        //Construct for the beverage
        public Soda(string _drinkName, string _drinkType, int _drinkPrice, int _productCode)
        {
            drinkName = _drinkName;
            drinkType = _drinkType;
            drinkPrice = _drinkPrice;
            productCode = _productCode;
        }

        //Property for the drink name e.g. Coca Cola, Ramlösa or Pripps lättöl
        public string Drink_name
        {
            get { return drinkName; }
            set { drinkName = value; }
        }

        //Property for the drink type e.g. Soda, fizzy water or beer
        public string Drink_type
        {
            get { return drinkType; }
            set { drinkType = value; }
        }

        //Property for the drink price in SEK
        public int Drink_price
        {
            get { return drinkPrice; }
            set { drinkPrice = value; }
        }

        //Property for the product code e.g. 1, 2 or ...
        public int Product_code
        {
            get { return productCode; }
            set { productCode = value; }
        }

        //Override for ToString to get text instead of info about the object
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return string.Format("{0} is a {1} costs {2} productcode {3} ", drinkName, drinkType, drinkPrice, productCode);
            //return string.Format("{0,0} Type {1,-16} Price {2,-10} Code {3, -5} ", drinkName, drinkType, drinkPrice, productCode);
        }

        //Compare to solve my issues with sorting
        public int CompareTo(Soda other)
        {
            if (other == null)
            {
                return 1;
            }

            return drinkName.CompareTo(other.drinkName);
        }

    }

    static class Screen
    {
        // Screen - Generic methods for handling in- and output ======================================= >

        // Methods for screen handling in this object are:
        //
        //  cls()       Clear screen
        //  cup(row, col)       Positions the curser to a position on the console
        //  inKey()             Reads one pressed key (Returned value is : ConsoleKeyInfo)
        //  inStr()         Handles String
        //  inInt()     Handles Int
        //  inFloat()       Handles Float(Singel)
        //  meny()              Menu system , first invariable is Rubrik and 2 to 6 meny choises
        //  addSodaMenu()       The options for adding bottles

        // Clear Screen  ------------------------------------------
        static public void cls()
        {
            Console.Clear();
        }

        // Set Curser Position  ----------------------------------
        static public void cup(int column, int rad)
        {
            Console.SetCursorPosition(column, rad);
        }

        // Key Input --------------------------------------------
        static public ConsoleKeyInfo inKey()
        {
            ConsoleKeyInfo in_key; in_key = Console.ReadKey(); return in_key;
        }

        // String Input -----------------------------------------
        static public string inStr()
        {
            string in_string; in_string = Console.ReadLine(); return in_string;
        }

        // Int Input -------------------------------------------
        static public int inInt()
        {
            int int_in; try { int_in = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); }
            catch (FormatException) { Console.WriteLine("Input Error \b"); int_in = 0; }
            catch (OverflowException) { Console.WriteLine("Input Owerflow\b"); int_in = 0; }
            return int_in;
        }

        // Float Input -------------------------------------------
        static public float inFloat()
        {
            float float_in; try { float_in = Convert.ToSingle(Console.ReadLine()); }
            catch (FormatException) { Console.WriteLine("Input Error \b"); float_in = 0; }
            catch (OverflowException) { Console.WriteLine("Input Owerflow\b"); float_in = 0; }
            return float_in;
        }

        // Menu ------------------------------------------------
        static public int meny(string rubrik, string m_val1, string m_val2)
        {  // Meny med 2 val ---------------------
            int menSvar; menyRubrik(rubrik); menyRad(m_val1); menyRad(m_val2); menSvar = menyInm();
            return menSvar;
        }

        static public int meny(string rubrik, string m_val1, string m_val2, string m_val3)
        {  // Meny med 3 val ---------------------
            int menSvar; menyRubrik(rubrik); menyRad(m_val1); menyRad(m_val2); menyRad(m_val3); menSvar = menyInm();
            return menSvar;
        }

        static public int meny(string rubrik, string m_val1, string m_val2, string m_val3, string m_val4)
        {  // Meny med 4 val ---------------------
            int menSvar; menyRubrik(rubrik); menyRad(m_val1); menyRad(m_val2); menyRad(m_val3); menyRad(m_val4); menSvar = menyInm();
            return menSvar;
        }

        static public int meny(string rubrik, string m_val1, string m_val2, string m_val3, string m_val4, string m_val5)
        {  // Meny med 5 val ---------------------
            int menSvar; menyRubrik(rubrik); menyRad(m_val1); menyRad(m_val2); menyRad(m_val3); menyRad(m_val4); menyRad(m_val5); menSvar = menyInm();
            return menSvar;
        }

        static public int meny(string rubrik, string m_val1, string m_val2, string m_val3, string m_val4, string m_val5, string m_val6)
        {  // Meny med 6 val ---------------------
            int menSvar; menyRubrik(rubrik); menyRad(m_val1); menyRad(m_val2); menyRad(m_val3); menyRad(m_val4); menyRad(m_val5); ; menyRad(m_val6); menSvar = menyInm();
            return menSvar;
        }

        static void menyRubrik(string rubrik)
        {   // Meny rubrik --------
            cls(); Console.WriteLine("\n\t {0}\n----------------------------------------------------\n", rubrik);
        }

        static void menyRad(string menyVal)
        {   // Meny rad    --------
            Console.WriteLine("\t {0}", menyVal);
        }

        static int menyInm()
        { // Meny inmating ------
            int mVal; Console.Write("\n\t Menyval : "); mVal = inInt(); return mVal;
        }

        // Menu for adding bottles --------------------------------
        static public void addSodaMenu()
        {
            cls();
            Console.WriteLine("\tChoose a beverage please.");
            Console.WriteLine("\t1. Coca Cola");
            Console.WriteLine("\t2. Champis");
            Console.WriteLine("\t3. Grappo");
            Console.WriteLine("\t4. Pripps Blå lättöl");
            Console.WriteLine("\t5. Spendrups lättöl");
            Console.WriteLine("\t6. Ramlösa citron");
            Console.WriteLine("\t7. Vichy Nouveu");
            Console.WriteLine("\t9. Exit to main menu");
            Console.WriteLine("\t--------------------\n");
        }

        // Screen - Slut  <========================================
    } // screen <----

    class Sodacrate
    {
        // Sodacrate - Methods for handling arrays and lists of Soda-objects ======================================= >

        // Methods for Soda handling in this object are:
        //
        //  cls()       Clear screen
        //
        //

        private Soda[] bottles;             //Create they array where we store the up to 25 bottles
        private int numberOfBottles = 0;          //Keep track of the number of bottles in the crate

        //Not working
        public int find_Soda(string drinkname)
        {
            //Notes from teatcher   **=================start==================**
            //You should be able to search for name
            //You can use string-methods ToLower() or ToUpper() 
            //Notes from teatcher   **=================end====================**

            for (int i = 0; i < bottles.Length; i++)
            {
                if (bottles[i].Drink_name == drinkname) //My feeble attempts
                    return i;
            }
            return -1;
        }

        //Exception error
        public void sort_Sodas()
        {
            int max = bottles.Length;
            //Outer loop for complete [bottles]
            for (int i = 1; i < max; i++)
            {
                //Inner loop for row by row
                int nrLeft = max - i;
                for (int j = 0; j < (max - i); j++)
                {
                    var bottle1 = bottles[j];
                    var bottle2 = bottles[j + 1];

                    if((bottle1 == null) || (bottle2 == null))
                    {
                        continue;
                    }

                    if (bottle1.Product_code > bottle2.Product_code)
                    {
                        var temp = bottles[j];
                        bottles[j] = bottles[j + 1];
                        bottles[j + 1] = temp;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        //Exception error
        public void sort_Sodas_name()
        {
            //var tempb = bottles.OrderBy(x => x.Drink_name).ToArray();
            //bottles = tempb;

            int max = bottles.Length;
            //Outer loop for complete [bottles]
            for (int i = 1; i < max; i++)
            {
                //Inner loop for row by row
                int nrLeft = max - i;
                for (int j = 0; j < (max - i); j++)
                {
                    var bottle1 = bottles[j];
                    var bottle2 = bottles[j + 1];

                    if ((bottle1 == null) || (bottle2 == null))
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                    //Error CS0122  'Soda.drinkName' is inaccessible due to its protection level
                    if (bottle1.Drink_name.CompareTo(bottle2.Drink_name) == 1)
                    {
                        var temp = bottles[j];
                        bottles[j] = bottles[j + 1];
                        bottles[j + 1] = temp;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        //Search for Product code ony returns the first hit
        public int LinearSearch(int key)
        {

            for (int i = 0; i < bottles.Length; i++)
            {
                if (bottles[i].Product_code == key)
                    return i;
            }
            return -1;
        }

        //Contains the menu to choose from the crates methods
        public void Run()
        {
            //Quick and dirty add of data. I got this working fine
            bottles[0] = new Soda("Coca Cola", "Soda", 5, 1);
            bottles[1] = new Soda("Champis", "Soda", 6, 1);
            bottles[2] = new Soda("Grappo", "Soda", 4, 1);
            bottles[3] = new Soda("Pripps Blå", "beer", 6, 2);
            bottles[4] = new Soda("Spendrups", "beer", 6, 2);
            bottles[5] = new Soda("Ramlösa", "water", 4, 3);
            bottles[6] = new Soda("Loka", "water", 4, 3);
            bottles[7] = new Soda("Coca Cola", "Soda", 5, 1);

            print_crate();  //Happy with this one I need to shape up the ToString override
            Console.WriteLine("\n\tYou have {0} bottles in your crate:\n\n", bottleCount());

            Console.WriteLine("\nTotal value of the crate is {0}", calc_total());//Happy as a clam

            int price = 0; //Causes exception error I lack understanding

            foreach (var bottle in bottles)
            {
                if (bottle == null)
                {
                    continue;
                }
                price = price + bottle.Drink_price;
            }

            Console.WriteLine("\tThe total value of the crate is {0} SEK.", price);

            Screen.inKey();
            Screen.cls();

            int test = 0;
            test = bottles[3].Product_code;//So bottles[i].xyz  do some things and bottles.xyz others
            Console.WriteLine("Product code {0} is in slot {1}", test, 3);
            Screen.inKey();

            //This only returns the first product with the asked productcode. How to get all? Also what if I searched for name like Coca Cola instead?
            Console.WriteLine("Type 1, 2 or 3");
            int prodcode = Screen.inInt();
            Console.WriteLine(LinearSearch(prodcode));
            Console.WriteLine("Product code {0} is in slot {1}", prodcode, (LinearSearch(prodcode)));
            Console.WriteLine(bottles[(LinearSearch(prodcode))]);

            Console.WriteLine("\nbefore sort\n");
            Screen.inKey();
            print_crate();
            Console.WriteLine("\nafter sort\n");
            sort_Sodas();         //Causes Exception error I want it to sort on either product code or product name
            print_crate();        //Check if the sort has put two Coca Cola on top.
            Console.WriteLine("\nafter sort name\n");
            sort_Sodas_name();
            print_crate();        //Check if the sort has put two Coca Cola on top.
        }

        //Print the content of the crate to the console
        public void print_crate()
        {
            foreach (var beverage in bottles)
            {
                if (beverage != null)
                    Console.WriteLine(beverage);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("\n\tYou have {0} bottles in your crate:", bottleCount());
        }

        //Construct, sets the Sodacrate to hold 25 bottles
        public Sodacrate()
        {
            bottles = new Soda[25];
        }

        // Count the ammounts of bottles in crate
        public int bottleCount()
        {
            int cnt = numberOfBottles;
            // Loop though array to get not empty element
            foreach (var beverages in bottles)
            {
                if (beverages != null)
                {
                    cnt++;
                }
            }
            return cnt;
        }

        //Calculates the total value of the bottles in the crate
        public int calc_total()
        {
            int temp = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < bottleCount(); i++)
            {
                temp = temp + (bottles[i].Drink_price);
            }
            return temp;
        }
        //Adds bottles in the crate.
        public void add_Soda()
        {
            //I start of with adding 7 bottles to avoid having to add so many bottles testing functions. Remove block before release 
            bottles[0] = new Soda("Coca Cola", "Soda", 5, 1);
            bottles[1] = new Soda("Champis", "Soda", 6, 1);
            bottles[2] = new Soda("Grappo", "Soda", 4, 1);
            bottles[3] = new Soda("Pripps Blå", "lättöl", 6, 2);
            bottles[4] = new Soda("Spendrups", "lättöl", 6, 2);
            bottles[5] = new Soda("Ramlösa citron", "mineralvatten", 4, 3);
            bottles[6] = new Soda("Vichy Nouveu", "mineralvatten", 4, 3);
            //<====================================== End block

            int beverageIn = 0;//Creates the menu choice-variable
            while (beverageIn != 9)//Exit this menu by typing 9 - This value should be different if we add more bottle types to add.
            {
                Screen.addSodaMenu();//Calls the menu in the Screen-class
                Console.WriteLine("You have {0} bottles in the crate.\n\nChoose :", bottleCount());
                Screen.cup(8, 13);
                int i = bottleCount();//Keeps track of how many bottles we have in the crate. If the crate is full we get expelled out of this method
                if (i == 25)
                { beverageIn = 9; }
                else beverageIn = Screen.inInt();//end

                switch (beverageIn) //Loop for adding bottles to the crate exit by pressing 9
                {
                    case 1:
                        i = bottleCount();
                        bottles[i] = new Soda("Coca Cola", "Soda", 5, 1);
                        i++;
                        break;

                    case 2:
                        i = bottleCount();
                        bottles[i] = new Soda("Champis", "Soda", 6, 1);
                        i++;
                        break;

                    case 3:
                        i = bottleCount();
                        bottles[i] = new Soda("Grappo", "Soda", 4, 1);
                        i++;
                        break;

                    case 4:
                        i = bottleCount();
                        bottles[i] = new Soda("Pripps Blå lättöl", "lättöl", 6, 2);
                        i++;
                        break;

                    case 5:
                        i = bottleCount();
                        bottles[i] = new Soda("Spendrups lättöl", "lättöl", 6, 2);
                        i++;
                        break;

                    case 6:
                        i = bottleCount();
                        bottles[i] = new Soda("Ramlösa citron", "mineralvatten", 4, 3);
                        i++;
                        break;

                    case 7:
                        i = bottleCount();
                        bottles[i] = new Soda("Vichy Nouveu", "mineralvatten", 4, 3);
                        i++;
                        break;

                    case 9:
                        i = bottleCount();
                        if (i == 25)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("\tThe crate is full\n\tGoing back to main menu. Press a key: ");
                        }
                        Console.WriteLine("Going back to main menu. Press a key: ");
                        break;

                    default://Default will never kick in as I have error handling in Screen.inInt()
                        Console.WriteLine("Error, pick a number between 1 and 7 or 9 to end.");
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
        // Sodacrate - End  <========================================
    }
}
```

I don't think I answered your first question but this should be enough to get going.

**EDIT**

Try this for the multiple product return:

```
public string LinearSearchMultiple(int productCode)
{
    var productCodes = string.Empty;

    for (int i = 0; i < bottles.Length; i++)
    {
        var bottle = bottles[i];
        if(bottle==null)
        {
            continue;
        }
        if (bottle.Product_code == productCode)
        {
            productCodes += bottle.ToString() + "\n";
        }
    }

    return productCodes;
}
```

You can call it like this:

```
int prodcode = Screen.inInt();
Console.WriteLine(LinearSearchMultiple(prodcode));
```

The output will be something like this if you enter 2:

> Pripps Blå is a beer costs 6 productcode 2
>
> Spendrups is a beer costs 6 productcode 2

Comment: Alex W: Thanks a million. That was some crucial misstakes I had done on my bubble sort. Your code and above all your comments solved my problems AND I feel confident that I will sourt out the find portion as well,If you ever go to Sweden, Stockholm I will set you up well and proper.
/Vincent